# Operations on the vector set $\mathbb{R}$ that will provide a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, real-numbers

Which operations on $\mathbb{R}$ will provide us with a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$?

i.e. if $\mathbb{R}$ is our vector set and our operations are defined by $\vec{x}+\vec{y}=f(x,y) \text{ and } c \cdot \vec{x}=g(c,x)$, which $f,g$ will give us a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ and are they unique?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are certainly not unique. For any *set bijection* $h\colon\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$, you can build new ring operations by defining
$$
f(x,y) = h^{-1}\big(h(x)+h(y)\big) \quad\text{and}\quad g(x,y) = h^{-1}\big(h(x)h(y)\big).
$$
This produces a ring with weird element labels but which is (by construction) isomorphic to the usual ring. A typical example comes from $h(x)=x+1$, so that the "addition" of $x$ and $y$ is defined by $x+y+1$ and "multiplication" by $xy+x+y$. But there are crazy many set bijections....

You can do similar things by making $h$ a set bijection to other vector spaces over $\Bbb R$, such as $\Bbb R^2$.