# Can there be different ring structures on the same set?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Say we have the set of real numbers. Can we construct a different ring than the usual ring of real numbers?

I am trying to wrap my head around the idea of rings and I couldn't find two other operations that will hold distributive property other than usual addition and multiplication.

If we can find another ring with the set of real numbers, is there a set with only one ring structure? If we can't find another ring with the set of real numbers, is there a set with different ring structures?

Comment: Definitely. Consider that $\Bbb Z$ and $\Bbb Q$, for example, can be considered the same set since they are in bijection. Their usual ring structures are clearly not-equivalent since $\Bbb Q$ is a field, for example.

Comment: Any set with two elements has precisely one ring structure: $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb C$ have the same cardinality (so are "the same" set), but the latter has a $\sqrt{-1}$ and the former does not. (And the $1$ is uniquely determined, as is its additive inverse, etc.)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a more explicit example if my comment about $\Bbb Z$ and $\Bbb Q$ was unconvincing.

Let $S=\{a,b,c,d\}$. Let $R_1$ be the ring structure on $S$ inherited from $\Bbb Z/(2)\times\Bbb Z/(2)$ under the bijection $a\mapsto (0,0)$, $b\mapsto (1,0)$, $c\mapsto (0,1)$, and $d\mapsto (1,1)$. For example, $ab=a$, $b+d=c$, and $cd=c$.

Now let $R_2$ be the ring on $S$ inherited from $\Bbb Z/(4)$ with the bijection $a\mapsto 0$, $b\mapsto 1$, $c\mapsto 2$, and $d\mapsto 3$.

You can verify that $R_1$ and $R_2$ are not isomorphic since, for example, $R_1$  has no element of (additive) order $4$.

Answer (score 4):

The other examples given are nice, but to give an example where the set is $\mathbb{R}$ as you were originally wondering about you take $\mathbb{R}$ with the normal multiplication but where we define the multiplication operation to always evaluate to $0$. Under this definition we have a different ring structure and it's certainly not isomorphic since this structure is not a field. This isn't a particularly nice ring since it doesn't have unity.

Comment: I don’t think that will be a unital ring since $(2)(2)=(1+1)(1+1)=(1)(1)+\cdots+(1)(1)=4$

Comment: @ElliotG correct, but OP didn't ask for that

Answer (score 4):

Given any bijection $\,f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R},\,$ define new addition and
multiplication operations by $\,x\oplus y:=f^{-1}(f(x)+f(y))\,$ and
$\,x\otimes y:=f^{-1}(f(x)\cdot f(y)).\,$ These two operations form
$\,\mathbb{R}\,$ into a ring isomorphic the the usual ring of reals.
As a concrete example, try $\,f(x):=x+1.\,$ This example is given in an answer to
[MSE question 1911294](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1911294)
"Operations on the vector set $\mathbb{R}$ that will provide a vector space".

Comment: Being isomorphic it is not  a "different ring structure". This is known as [transport of structure](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a242%20transport%20structure)

Comment: @BillDubuque That depends on exactly what the definition of "different ring structure" is. The question was not precise on that point. I did mention that the new ring is isomorphic to the original ring. Finding a non  trivial non isomorphic ring on $\mathbb{R}$ is a much more difficult question.